# Hasura webhook auth with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, hasura

My question is more in line of designing the webhook architecture with Amazon Cognito. I came up with following design after going through hasura's documentation on webhook auth. Is it feasible? Note: AWS lambda is behind API gateway with Authorization enabled.

[image]

Now,

- Don't you think its overhead for app to authenticate as well as hasura for every request?
- Can this be achieved without lambda in between hasura and cognito?
- Can hasura provide the authentication based on user credentials to the app and webhook to verify that in the Cognito?

Thank for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question as you. After trying lots of methods, I think using Hasura JWT mode is a good way and it works well without any complex configuration. Take a look at this flow:

1. React App request the token from Cognito
2. Cognito triggers PreTokenGeneration to add Hasura claims
3. React App get the `idToken`(with Hasura claims) from Cognito

I think it will be much better to separate the auth and the data.

NOTE: 
Cognito hasn't support the dict type of claim value. So you should set `claims_format: 'stringified_json'` in Hasura jwt-secret. You can take a look at this issue: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1176

FYI: 
* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html
* https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/jwt.html#

Comment: Where do you keep the token at the client? How do you handle refreshing it?